# LaTeX Error: File `l3backend-pdftex.def' not found

Tags: pdftex, texlive, texmaker

I'm currently starting with LaTeX and I got the following error:

> LaTeX Error: File `l3backend-pdftex.def' not found.Type X to quit or
>  to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: def)Enter
> file name:! Emergency stop. { \sys_load_backend:n { } }

I'm using Texmaker and Tex Live on Windows 10. Tbh I'm not sure how to "connect" those two, i.e. how it in principle works.

My code is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl} 
\begin{document}
    First LaTeX document
\end{document}
```

Comment: Replace scrartcl by article (to make the log shorter), compile and show the complete log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you for the advice! Changing scartcl to article helped, now I don't get the error anymore

Comment: But that wasn't the intention. I only wanted to see your pathes. What happens if you add a package which needs expl3 like \usepackage{xparse}?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, okay. I tried this and this is what I get:
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6880 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.11.17) 8 DEC 2021 13:25
entering extended mode
**./proba.tex
(proba.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size11.clo"
File: size11.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
Is this part of the log helpful?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer because if I copy the whole log, I'm ca. 6500 characters over the limit

Comment: well your latex is quite old. But if it looks for l3backend-pdftex.def then some parts are newer and this not longer fits. Probably you install something later with the on-the-fly installation. Check in the miktex console for updates in user *and* admin mode to get a consistent system again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay, I will try it. Thank you! 
But which is actually old, the Texmaker or Tex Live ? Or both? 
I still don't understand the difference

Comment: Texmaker is an editor, thus not relevant here. It is your miktex (you're not using texlive) that is rather old, seems it haven't been fully updated since 2018. Do as Ulrike says, she knows mikrex quite welk

Comment: @daleif okay, but first I have to finde the miktex console. An I downloaded Texlive also. Do I have to manually change that I want to use Texlive and not miktex?

Comment: Change what? Texlive uses a different approach when it comes to updates.

Comment: @daleif as I understand, you can either use MikTex as an Latex distribution OR Tex Live. And because you said that I used Miktex in my example, not Tex live, my question is how can I switch to tex live

Comment: If you want to use texlive, then --- assuming that you correctly installed it --- you have to add the path to the binaries to your PATH environment variable. The path is normally `C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32`. Or if you already have it in the path, you will have to move it before the path to the miktex binaries. Check in a terminal with `where pdftex`, it will report everyone it can find.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer okay, I will try it. Thank you!